# Url blocked by robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I badly stuck on error in webmaster tools. I have created Sitemap and when I try to  test it on webmaster tools it showing me this below error:

```
Issue : Url blocked by robots.txt
    Description : Sitemap contains urls which are blocked by robots.txt
```

However when I removed robots.txt file from server still it was showing me this above error. I have no idea how I can get rid from it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a little bit of time for any changes to robots.txt to reflect in GWT.  If you just made the changes, give it 24-48 hours.